# SSMS - Do some statements under transaction then interactively inspect before rollback/commit?

Tags: t-sql, ssms

In building a script that will run against a production SQL Server I'd like to build and test it *interactively*.

I.e., create a script with a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` followed with some statements to delete and/or insert and/or update, possibly in batches if required.  Then I'd like to execute the script in a query window and with the transaction still active proceed to query the database (in that window? in a different window?) in various ways to see how it *would* look if the transaction was committed, and then finally rollback.

Is this possible?  Or what should I be doing instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best to do testing on a PreProd server, but it's technically possible to do what you're saying.

If you begin a transaction and then run some statements, with no `COMMIT`, you can then query the affected tables in another window, by first declaring `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED`. When you're done, you can then go back to the first window and execute a `ROLLBACK` statement.